Glade and Ocaml?
I'm currently working on a project in Ocaml (I love this language), and I need to create a graphical interface. I've tried LabelGTK, it works but it's REALLY tiring... As a regular Glade user, I'd like to be able to use it, but I can't find anything on it... Just an old page from 2009 that gives an example code but without the library that goes with it...
I know that using an xml file to create a GUI in Ocaml is a bit of a shame (since Ocaml is statically typed and reading an unsafe, modifiable file into it is a bit counter-productive), but I'd like to not have to bother with LabelGTK...
Thanks in advance for your answers!

If you're looking for an OCaml library, I suggest checking opam. conf-glade Documentation does seem a bit thin.

I actually found it but I don't see any documentation...

When I said "a bit thin" I may have been understating the situation. :)
